Postfix mail forwarding SPF failure, SRS failure
I run a postfix/dovecot mailserver on Ubuntu 24 which as well as having mailboxes on the server, does some forwarding out to external mailboxes e.g. gmail. Gmail recieves this mail and SPF checks have failed as the mail was processed by my server which isn't approved by the sending address. I researched and discovered SRS Sender Rewriting.
apt install postsrsd

I added my domains to SRS_EXCLUDE_DOMAINS= in /etc/default/postsrsd. I then added the following to  main.cf:
# Use postsrsd to rewrite the Return-Path: header
sender_canonical_maps = tcp:localhost:10001
sender_canonical_classes = envelope_sender
recipient_canonical_maps = tcp:localhost:10002
recipient_canonical_classes= envelope_recipient,header_recipient

Now this is causing incoming mail that isn't being externally relayed to bounce due to failed dmarc. E.g. internal catch all forwarders that forward INTERNALLY and mail inbound directly to a mailbox are being rewritten and failing.
And now I'm getting errors like Messages with multiple 550-5.7.1 addresses in From: header are not accepted..

This does not contain enough information to reproduce. You changed one thing with caused problems with other (undisclosed) configuration.
